# Display Bootstrap HTML with .CSS links inside XSL stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, xslt, ibm-datapower

What I am trying to do here is display my HTML page when I run a XSL style sheet. The HTML with .CSS links is embedded inside my XSL. There is no .XML file in this case. I am trying to output the Bootstrap HTML page when the .XSL style sheet is executed. The HTML seems to working as I would expect the .CSS style sheets are not working.

Here is the .xsl

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

                            <html lang="en">
                              <head>
                                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
                                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                                <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->


                                   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
                                <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                                <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
                                <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


                                <meta name="description" content="Error Page"/>
                                <meta name="author" content="AXA Datapower Team"/>
                                <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico"/>

                                <title>Error Page</title>

                                <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
                                <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
                                <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

                                <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                                  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                                  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                                <![endif]-->

                              </head>

                              <body>

                               <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                                  <div class="container">
                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AXA Equitable</a>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </nav>
                                -->

                                <div class="container">

                                  <div class="starter-template">
                                    <!--<img src="images/warning.png" alt="Error" class="img-rounded">
                                    <img src="images/error-7-xxl.png" alt="Error" class="img-rounded">
                                    <img src="images/exclamation.png" alt="Error" class="img-rounded">-->
                                    <img src="warning-xxl.png" alt="Error" class="img-rounded"/>

                                    <h1>An unexpected error has occurred.</h1>
                                    <p class="lead">Please contact your system administrator for assistance.</p>

                                  </div>

                                </div><!-- /.container -->


                                <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
                                ================================================== -->
                                <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
                                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
                                <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
                              </body>
                            </html>
                </xsl:template>
```

These are the .CSS style sheets that are not being processed:

```
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
                                <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                                <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
                                <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I am running the .XSL page in IBM DataPower. The HTML displays in the browser but with no .CSS Style. Is this simply because the .CSS is not pointing to the correct location on DataPower or is the problem more complicated?

If anyone can help me out here that would be great. This is a simple error page. nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

I did an inline style sheet and it works fine. I must not have been linking the correct path to the .CSS withing Datapower.